# C++ Static storage duration objects initialization before main()

Tags: c++, static, initialization, global, program-entry-point

Suppose we have some global object subjected to dynamic initialization:

```
class A {
    A() { std::cout << "constructor\n"; }
};
A global_a; // Here it is

// Other translation unit
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

> C++14 §3.6.2 clause 4
>
> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is done before the first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized

This means that an implementation is *not required* to initialize our object before main() even though all compilers I know do that. This is unfortunate since sometimes it is very convenient to have such guarantee, e.g. for independent self-registering factories residing in a separate file, etc.

So I came up with the following: what if we define some inline function:

```
inline void f(){}
```

in every translation unit (supposedly using a common header).
Then in the beggining of main() we odr-use it in some way:

```
int main()
{
    f();
    //...
}
```

Will this guarantee that all the translation units which provide a definition for f() will have their global objects initialized at this point?

Comment: wouldnt `(void)(&f);` be optimized away once you turn on optimizations?

Comment: It probably would, although here it doesn't really matter

Comment: Can you assign your `f()` some job to do, for example (atomically) altering a `volatile` non-static variable. This will prevent compiler from making any assumptions about function doing nothing

Comment: Optimizations are a red herring : the compiler is not allowed to change the behaviour of the program when optimizing.

Comment: @Quentin the behaviour does not change, as `f` does not have any behaviour other than trying to force order of initializations, which in turn is implementation-defined

Comment: @tobi303 triggering the initialization is an observable, well-defined side-effect of the ODR-use of `f`, even if `f` itself does nothing. Removing that side-effect would be breaking the as-if rule.

Comment: @Quentin I might be completely wrong, but I wouldnt expect that optimizations have to restrict to a "compile as-if". As I understand, the as-if rule does not include things that are undefined/unspecified anyhow. However, instead of spamming maybe I should do some reading ;)

Comment: @tobi303 Maybe it's me who's missing something, but the quoted paragraph clearly states that, whenever the initialization happens (this is implementation defined), it shall be before the first ODR-use of `f` (this is well-defined). The only possible span is beween `main`'s opening brace and `&f`, which is reduced to nothing here, so IMO this has to work as expected.

Comment: I've replaced &f with an actual call since it seems that parts of discarded expressions are not counted as odr-used. A call, however, is definitely odr-using f.

Answer (score 1):

Technically? **Yes**, per the quote you provided and the definition of *odr-use*.

In practice I'm not sure I'd rely on it. I can well imagine compilers optimising `f()` away and having some bug that then ruins what you're trying to rely on. Though I have no data to support this; it just seems like a prime candidate for non-compliance, based on experience.

If you want to really, really ensure that something happens when your program starts up, on balance it might be better to invoke some "initialisation" function on `global_a` at the top of `main`. I realise that's an anti-pattern.

Comment: Well, since all the compilers I know of already initalize global objects before main(), I don't have anything to worry about. This question is more theoretic than practical. I just would be glad to know that my code is guaranteed to work correctly with a fully-compliant compiler

Comment: @dsi: With a fully-compliant compiler? Yes, absolutely. But I've never seen a fully-compliant compiler.